# Should and can we minify the css in an email

Tags: css, email, html-email

I'm using http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ for emails on my website.
I was asking myself if the css in an email can be minified to like, 1 line, or if it should'nt be modified ?

Comment: strictly speaking you can have one line of continuous CSS and it will work, but it wont look very pretty.

Comment: If you have load time issues in an email it's unlikely to be caused by CSS. I wouldn't bother. Spend your time optimizing images and cross-testing your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, I would use the CSS code as it is presented.  If the boilerplate team put the code in like that, then they did it for a good reason *and also because they tested and debugged their code too*.  I would say at the very least, it is probably safe to remove the excessive comments if no one else on your team needs to read them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the code has tons of comments. Since it's for production, removing the comments at least is good.

There's no *harm* in fully minifying it. No real need either, bu you can do it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can compress your code by throwing multiple things onto single lines, but you'll get most benefit from simply removing the excess commented sections. Here's an example of part of the boilerplate I've condensed to shorten it up a bit:

```
  /* Hotmail */
  .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {color: black !important;} h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {color: blue !important;}
  h1 a:active, h2 a:active,  h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active { color: red !important; } h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited,  h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited { color: purple !important; }
  /* Outlook */
  table td {border-collapse: collapse;} #outlook a {padding:0;} #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
  /* Yahoo */
  p {margin: 1em 0;}
```